# What's the right way to get a branch in sync with master after a squash and merge?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Before squash and merge

```
master : a->b
branch1: a->b->c->d
branch2: a->b->c->d->e
```

After squash and merge `branch1` to `master` (i.e. `c->d` became `f`)

```
master : a->b->f
branch2: a->b->c->d->e
```

How do I sync `branch2` with `master`? (i.e. reflect the `c->d` squash into `f`)

I'd try merge and then resolve conflicts, but that would entail another commit which doesn't seem to be the best way.

I tried rebase. After resolving conflicts, git logs show `f` on top of `c->d` (i.e `c->d->f`) as opposed to replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried rebase. After resolving conflicts, git logs show f on top of c->d (i.e c->d->f) as opposed to replacing it."

You rebased wrong. You neglected to explain to Git that branch2 was built off of branch1. The correct command was

```
 git switch branch2
 git rebase --onto master branch1
```

Comment: Doing this got `branch2` in sync with `master` but I lost commit `e`.
`master: a->b->f`
`branch2: a->b->f`

Comment: Given your original diagram I stand behind my answer. What you had when you gave the commands I suggested, I have no idea.